# GroupBy Email & get earliest created_at date in Group - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I get the earliest created_at date when using groupBy in an eloquent statement?

I have a table with the following:

```
| id | name   | email   | created_at          |
|----|--------|---------|---------------------|
| 1  | test   | 1@1.com | 2018-01-01 09:00:00 |
| 2  | test   | 1@1.com | 2018-01-02 09:00:00 |
| 3  | test 2 | 2@2.com | 2018-01-02 09:00:00 |
| 4  | test 2 | 2@2.com | 2018-01-03 09:00:00 |
| 5  | test   | 1@1.com | 2018-01-03 09:00:00 |
| 6  | test   | 1@1.com | 2018-01-04 09:00:00 |
| 7  | test   | 1@1.com | 2018-01-05 09:00:00 |
| 8  | test 3 | 3@3.com | 2018-01-06 09:00:00 |
| 9  | test 3 | 3@3.com | 2018-01-07 09:00:00 |
```

when running the following query:

```
Customers::OrderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('email')->paginate('5');
```

I was expecting to get the results in the following order:

```
Test 3 (created: 2018-01-07)
Test   (created: 2018-01-05)
Test 2 (created: 2018-01-03)
```

But instead I am getting so it doesn't look like it's respecting the OrderBy

```
Test 3 (created: 2018-01-06)
Test 2 (created: 2018-01-02)
Test   (created: 2018-01-01)
```

Here is the SQL fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89ee39/2

# EDIT - Answer based on response

Thanks to Nesku, finally query to get this working was:

```
 return DB::table('customers')
        ->select(DB::raw('email, max(created_at)'))
        ->groupBy('email')
        ->orderBy('max(created_at)', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't order by `created_at` because it contains multiples values, you can however take the max of `created_at` for each email and order by that.

The SQL query would look like this :

```
SELECT email, max(created_at)
FROM `customers`
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY max(created_at) DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89ee39/12